# Disable support for chunked encoding

Tags: http, browser, chunked-encoding

Is there a way to disable chunked encoding support in a browser?

Comment: Why? Also, you should specify which browser and platform

Comment: Don't you rather mean "in a server"? :)

Comment: And if you do mean "in a server", then the question is, "What platform?"

Comment: I know how to do it on the serverside. I was trying to figure out what the performance change would be on same site same page, chunked on vs off. (problem is I dont have access to the site - not mine). Any of these browser platform, Chrome, Firefox, IE

Comment: @timeitquery. Turning chunked encoding on / off will not likely make a significant difference. There is no header (that I am aware of) that allows you to request non-chunked encoding, so you are stuck with what the server gives you.

Comment: @timeitquery Is this a very large page or something? The question feels rather exotic.

Comment: Theoretically, if you can make the browser request HTTP/1.0, the server side should disable chunked encoding.

Comment: Use an HTTP/1.0 proxy server.